# I have hosted a site which give reponse Blocked because of Dos Attack?

Tags: cloudflare

Website is hosted on Ubuntu server.

Website dns is managed using cloudflare.

Some time it throws page as the below image.
[image]

I am not able to figure out from where is this page is coming from.

how to find who has been blocking this.
how to solve this issue.

Comment: This is very likely coming from Cloudflare.  If you are behind Carrier Grade NAT you likely cant find out who is causing the issye.  If you are using regular NAT it is triggered by a device on your LAN. Maybe teach out to Cloudflare in the first instabce, as if its your website it may be a false alarm??¿

Comment: @davidgo if it is blocked by cloudflare then there should be blocked interface of cloudflare, but it is interface by fortigate firewall? am i wrong ?

Comment: What do you have as URL in your address bar at that moment?